# Можно ли в Android Studio добавить дополнительные папки с ресурсами?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, resources

В обычном проекте AS есть папка с ресурсами - res в ней обычно содержатся все использующиеся ресурсы. Я узнал что в ней можно создать папку - raw в которой можно хранить что хочу и с ней не возникает проблем при сборке проекта. Можно ли в папке src создать подпапки с ресурсами так чтобы при компиляции не возникало ошибок и ресурсы определялись?

Например у меня в проекте много изображений и не удобно их хранить только в папке drawable, я бы хотел создать drawable_1, drawable_2 и так далее.

Добавил как написано ниже:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = [
                    'src/main/res',
                    'src/main/res/drawable',
                    'src/main/res/drawable/images'
        ]
    }
}
```

При сборке проекта Gradle выдает следующую ошибку:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
C:\SDKandroid\desisns\AppName\app\src\main\res\drawable\images\one.jpg:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Answer (score 2):

Создайте папку `drawable2` в папке `drawable`

В `build.gradle`

```
sourceSets {
main {
    res.srcDirs =
    [
            'src/main/res/drawable/drawable2',
            'src/main/res/drawable',
            'src/main/res'
    ]
}
}
```

Обращаться к ресурсу `cat.png` из папки `drawable2` нужно: в коде - `R.drawable.drawable2.cat`, в `xml` - `@drawable/drawable2/cat`.

А, вообще, если картинок много, то лучше создать папку `assets` и реализовать там любую иерархию.
В папке `assets` создайте папку `animals` и в ней картинку `cat.png`. Чтобы получить картинку в коде, используйте, например, этот код

```
public Drawable getDrawableFromAssets(String path) {
Drawable img = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open(path), null);
return img;
}
```

Ну и, вот так, к примеру

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(getDrawableFromAssets("animals/cat.png"));
```

Comment: Пишет такую ошибку: Error:(1, 1) Error: Content is not allowed in prolog

Comment: где и кто пишет?

Comment: Gradle пишет ошибку:

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> C:\SDKandroid\desisns\App\app\src\main\res\images\main.jpg:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.