# Использование drawable в Android

Tags: android, android-studio

У меня очень много картинок, которые надо использовать и вот в чем вопросы...

1. Подскажите утилиту которая делает из несколько изображений от mdpi до xxhdpi
2. Если я в папку drawable закину еще пару папок с картинками , то смогу ли я вызывать их ? (Например путь будет drawable/pac1/pa2/image.png если могу использовать , то как?

Comment: вопрос должен содержать только одну проблему. Если у вас несколько проблем, оформите несколько вопросов. Заголовок каждого вопроса должен содержать суть проблемы в вопросе, а не общие слова. Это нужно для того, что данный ресурс - база практических решений, где другие участники могут воспользоваться уже отвеченными ранее вопросами, а не персональная бесплатная помощь нуждающимся в ней.

Comment: ответ по [второму вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/626418/177345), но делать в каталогах ресурсов подкаталоги не рекомендуется, так как они [обрабатываются квалификаторами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453000/177345), подкаталоги сильно запутают эту систему  (если очень надо, есть папка /assets). В дальнейшем старайтесь следовать правилам данного ресурса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. В самом `AndroidStudio` и можно делить картинки на нужные размеры, щелкните правой кнопкой по директории `Res` `New` `ImageAsset` `AssetType` укажите `Image` далее укажите путь до вашей картинки, и укажите имя картинки, программа сама раскинет фото по нужным папкам с нужными размерами.
2. Скорее всего да, по идее проблем в этом быть не должно.

Comment: А на счет 2 подробнее можно? Не гуглится и у самого не получается...

Comment: Вы создаете директорию в `Drawable` и не можете получить доступ к картинкам в этой директории?