# Как создать подпапку в папке res?Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

Я хочу создать подпапку в папке Res ,вставляю это build.gradel

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res',
                       'src/main/res/qwe']

    }
}
```

,но папка не добавляет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте переключить тип отображения, чтобы показывало проект целый

Comment: может она пустая?

Comment: нет она не пуста

Comment: Для чего она вам, что в ней будет лежать?

Comment: переключите тип отображения в дереве проекта с Android на Project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не можете создавать свои ресурсные папки в Android, их список и доступное содержимое четко определены. Если вам необходимо добавить данные, не подходящие под стандартные ресурсные папки - положите их  в папку assets. Если вы хотите как-то организовать свои файлы, которых стало слишком много, почитайте [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626417/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-android-studio-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) ответ

Comment: все же мы [можем создавать свои папки ресурсов](https://habr.com/ru/post/303926/) в проекте (так же [офф.документация](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#configure-sourcesets). Проблема автора вопроса видимо в том, что он не выбрал отображение Project вместо Android

Comment: Ну ладно, хоть что-то. Спасибо